# VirtualBox installation stalled for apparent disk space

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox

Atempting to install 16.04 in a VirtualBox installation, the process stalls because of the alloted size to the virtual machine.  [image]

Ubuntu will run in trial mode, but not install.  How can this error be overcome?

Comment: Did you try to increase the size of the virtual disk drive?

Comment: Yeap, just increase the size of the virtual drive and it should install fine.

Comment: OK. that does work.  But it is curious as instructions point to potentially smaller virtual drive sizes...